Android. AppWidgetProvider. RemoteViews. Создание Bitmap из CustomView
Виджеты рабочего стола Android не поддерживают в layout файле использование customView. см https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews. Из чего появилась идея создать из кастомной view bitmap и разместить в ImageView. Но при создании Bitmap arc отрисовывается некорректно, заливая всю отведенную есть область, причем в приложении рассчеты корректны. Любые идеи почему так происходит ?
Как создаю view  и bitmap из нее:
  val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)

  fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
     val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
         view.width, 
         view.height, 
         Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
     )
     val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
     view.draw(canvas)
     return bitmap
  } 

  val myView = MyView(context)
  myView.measure(size, size)
  myView.layout(0, 0, size, size)

  views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, getBitmapFromView(myView))


Пробовал:

добавлять в манифест android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
Видел что у кого-то были проблемы с методом canvas.drawArc(). Пробовал сделать тоже самое через canvas.drawPath(), но безрезультатно

Как view выглядит в приложении, и что получается на выходе при преобразовании в bitmap:



Используйте paint.setStyle( Paint.Style.STROKE );

Спасибо, все оказалось просто) При создании view из макета у меня инициализировались кисти, а здесь же при создании view из кода атрибуты не устанавливались в положенном месте. Я искал проблему в преобразовании в bitmap
